# libselinux-python bindings and ansible

Tags: python, ansible, libselinux

Sorry for answering my own question, but I've seen this crop up in multiple forums, so I wanted to post this in hope it helps someone else.

The basic problem occurs when trying to run Ansible against older Python interpreters -- particularly Python 2.6 on RedHat 5 -- and getting error messages about 'libselinux bindings not available' or similar errors.

While this could happen for any Python-based application, I see it most commonly on Ansible.  Ansible presumes the selinux module is available and will always attempt to import it at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The libselinux-python bindings are not a simple python module.  The module must be cross-compiled against both the target version of Python *and* the target version of libselinux.  The nice folks maintaining the RedHat 5 EPEL repositories did not generate a Python 2.6/libselinux 1.33 module.

The 'existing' libselinux-python module from the standard repos will not work, because it is specific to the supplied Python 2.4 interpreter.  If you copied the module from a different Python 2.6 install -- say, a RedHat 6 system -- that won't work either, because it's built against the wrong version of libselinux.  While you can amuse yourself with the various errors created by different combinations, Ansible won't bother to distinguish between them; it will just state that the bindings are unavailable.

The solution is to create a 'stub' selinux python module to pacify Ansible.  Create a file

```
 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/__init__.py
```

with the following contents:

```
def is_selinux_enabled():
  return False

def is_selinux_mls_enabled():
  return False
```

(This is Python code, so mind the indents.)  This effectively disables Ansible from working with selinux.  Also, tasks running against these systems should not include any selinux attributes, such as **setype** or **seuser**.  (Honestly, I haven't tested it fully.)  But basic modules like **lineinfile** or **command** now work properly.

This does not required disabling selinux; it only prevents Ansible from manipulating selinux attributes.  If necessary, you can always use the one of the **command** modules to script around it.

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to post this as a comment to the @crankyeldergod's answer (as his response lead me to figure out my fix to this issues) but I don't have enough posts to comment yet.

I also kept receiving the `"Aborting, target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"` error despite having the libselinux-python packages installed.  I went into `/usr/lib64` and checked the python directories I found there until I located the one with selinux files present.  I made note of that version of python and declared it explicitly in my inventory file, ie - `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.6` in my case and that resolved the issue.

Comment: This is a good point; make sure to be using the right python version.  I could not use it, the older RHEL does not have a compatible Python version with the bindings available..